# How to sum the nlargest() integers in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    Index STNAME COUNTY COUNTY_POP
      0     AL     0       100
      1     AL     1       150
      2     AL     3       200
      3     AL     5       50
    ...
     15     CA     0       300
     16     CA     1       200
     17     CA     3       250
     18     CA     4       350
```

I want to sum the three largest integers from COUNTY_POP for each state. So far, I have:

```
    In[]: df.groupby(['STNAME'])['COUNTY_POP'].nlargest(3)
    Out[]:
    Index STNAME COUNTY COUNTY_POP
      0     AL     0       100
      1     AL     1       150
      2     AL     3       200
    ...
     15     CA     0       300
     17     CA     3       250
     18     CA     4       350
```

However when I add the .sum() operation to the above code, I receive the following output.

```
    In[]: df.groupby(['STNAME'])['COUNTY_POP'].nlargest(3).sum()
    Out[]:
    1350
```

I'm relatively new to Python and Pandas. If anyone could explain what causes this and how to correct it, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [25]: df.groupby('STNAME')['COUNTY_POP'].agg(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum())
Out[25]:
STNAME
AL    450
CA    900
Name: COUNTY_POP, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This worked great, @MaxU! Thank you. Can you explain the use of .agg() and lambda?

Answer (score 2):

presort and slice... a tad faster

```
df.sort_values('COUNTY_POP').groupby('STNAME').COUNTY_POP \
    .apply(lambda x: x.values[-3:].sum())

STNAME
AL    450
CA    900
Name: COUNTY_POP, dtype: int64
```

Comment: this is only faster for very small groups - this is the point of nlargest it doesn't need to sort

Comment: @Jeff thank you for the clarification